# How set_fact on Ansible server list with component name

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I got an inventory look like this

```
       fruit:
         hosts:
           serverA: {component_name: component_a}
           serverB: {component_name: component_a}
           ServerC: {component_name: component_a}
      meat:
         hosts:
           serverD: {component_name: component_a}
           serverE: {component_name: component_a}
           ServerF: {component_name: component_a}
```

how can I get server as list based on the component name and meat as condition with set-fact?
expected result

```
{
ServerD
ServerE
ServerF
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For example, this inventory

```yaml
group_1:
  hosts:
    serverA: {var: a}
    serverB: {var: b}
    serverC: {var: a}
group_2:
  hosts:
    serverD: {var: b}
    serverE: {var: a}
    serverF: {var: b}
```

and playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        list_a: "{{ hostvars|
                    dict2items|
                    json_query('[?value.var==`a`].key') }}"
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: list_a
      run_once: true
    - set_fact:
        list_a1: "{{ list_a|
                     intersect(groups.group_1) }}"
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: list_a1
      run_once: true
```

give

```yaml
    "list_a": [
        "serverA",
        "serverC",
        "serverE"
    ]

    "list_a1": [
        "serverA",
        "serverC"
    ]
```

---

> Q: *"template error while templating string: no filter named 'dict2items'"*

A: [dict2items](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#dict-filter) is available since version 2.6. Use the tasks below if `dict2items` filter is not available.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_hostvars: "{{ my_hostvars|default([]) +
                         [{'key': item, 'value': hostvars[item]}] }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
      run_once: true
    - set_fact:
        list_a: "{{ my_hostvars|
                    json_query('[?value.var==`a`].key') }}"
      run_once: true
```

Comment: I have tried it have an error  "template error while templating string: no filter named 'dict2items'"

Comment: [dict2items](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#dict-filter) is available since version 2.6. Upgrade to [maintained versions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html#release-status).